# Unity collision with color (color limit the player's movement)

Tags: unity-game-engine

everyone! I have intresting issue. I need to create game with color collision. I have 2 players and both can move only in their color area. Both players can paint on enemy area using brush to change enemy color on player color. It should **add** area (accessible to move) for player and **remove** area from enemy.

Right now I use texture paint to create new texture with new colors each frame. It's okey. But how can I color limit the player's movement? Now I'm drawing 2 additional textures. One with the color of Player1 and the transparent alpha of Player2. And vice versa. Then, for these two textures, I create a polygon collider **every frame** to update the physical boundaries based on the drawn colors. And this is already very expensive.. How can I make the player's movement be limited by color without recalculating colliders every frame? And so that physics remains normal.

Comment: I would experiment with raycasting downward from the players to the ground and checking the raycast's position on the texture.

Comment: For example: in this project, the author used raycasting from the car wheels to draw a dislocation map at runtime and it creates trails in the snow: https://github.com/jjacobson/Realtime-Snow

Comment: Yes I thought about raycasting, but how I can use it to collide with this texture?